# jQuery animated number counter from zero to value on hover of Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  }
});
```

Digit

**I need a jQuery animated number counter from zero to value on hover of anchor tag section , is that even possible ?**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">150</span>
```

Comment: Where is that "svg section"?

Comment: you can show me on hovering on anchor tag

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
function startCounter() {
  const maxCounter = $('.Single').data('counter');
  $({
    Counter: 0
  }).animate({
    Counter: maxCounter
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
}

$('#magic').on('mouseenter', startCounter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single" data-counter="250"></span><br/>
<a id="magic" href="#">Hover me</a>
```

Comment: Thank You, While hovering second time the digits are not counting

Comment: @JabirSayed Try removing line `$('#magic').unbind();`

Comment: What if the single class value is set of 250 or any other numbers?

Comment: @JabirSayed see my updated answer. Now the counter max is inside the `data-counter` attribute of `Single` class.